# proficient asp.net and csharp programming using only opensource tools

Tags: c#, .net

Is it feasible to become proficient with msft dotNet using only opensource (or no-fee tools from msft)

if yes, what is the toolset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also:

- [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/)
- [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) (though not strictly the whole framework includes mono develop)
- Roll your own directly with any editor, MSBuild and the SDK

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  The [Express Editions](http://www.microsoft.com/express/product/) of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

And if you need a relational database [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/default.aspx) and [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) are free.

Answer (score 1):

If by open source you mean free these are a good start:

- [Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/exPress/download/)
- [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php)
- [Some DI Framework](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx)
- [Git](http://git-scm.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Express is a free download from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, however only to an extent. The free stuff like Microsoft Visual Studio Express is a great start for hobbyist and can help you practice the fundamentals. But you need the paid version for advance tools/features like code analysis. The advance tools help you do the powerful stuff and can reduce the amount of code you write and errors you create.